# Django ALLOWED_HOSTS and CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS settings not fully understood

Tags: python, django, nginx

My Django server is running on 127.0.0.1:8001. I use nginx to reverse proxy my django server to port 80.

The nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    location /static {
        root STATIC_ROOT;
    }
}
```

I got confused when I try to understand `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` settings.

These 2 settings all don't work:

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["example.com"]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://example.com"]
```

Or

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1"]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://127.0.0.1"]
```

**Only this works**

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1"]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://example.com"]
```

Can anybody explains why I need to set them differently?

If possible, how does nginx reverse proxy work generally?

Answer (score 1):

When your browser sends a request to the server, it sets several headers:

- `Host`, which specifies the host and port number of the server to which the request is being sent. [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host)
- `Origin` which indicates the origin (scheme, hostname, and port) that caused the request. For example, if a user agent needs to request resources included in a page, or fetched by scripts that it executes, then the origin of the page may be included in the request. [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin)

At the first step, when you open the page at `https://example.com` and make an HTTP request, it sends the following headers along with others: `Host: https://example.com` (what is requested) and `Origin: https://example.com` (from which page in the browser the request is sent).

At the second step, your request comes to nginx. By default, Nginx rewrites `Host` header to the proxy host itself. For example, for

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://another.example.com:8080;
}
```

nginx sets `Host` header to `http://another.example.com:8080`.

Therefore when it sends the request further to the server, `Host` header is no longer `https://example.com` in your case, but `$proxy_host` nginx variable which is taken from `proxy_pass` directive.

At the third step, Django receives the request and validates `Origin` and `Host` headers. By default, Django checks that these two headers are equal. If any vars are configured, Django takes them into concern as well.

So, to summarize:

After nginx you have `Host: http://127.0.0.1:8001` and `Origin: https://example.com`

It doesn't work in default conf because headers don't match.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["example.com"]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://example.com"]
```

doesn't work because Host is `http://127.0.0.1:8001` and you only allow `example.com`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1"]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://127.0.0.1"]
```

doesn't work because Origin is `https://example.com` and you only allow `http://127.0.0.1`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1"]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://example.com"]
```

works because it matches provided headers.

Comment: One probably shouldn't allow 127.0.0.1, but configure nginx to pass the host header to Django and then allow the correct domain in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.